# Magento 2: Multiple choice swatch attribute

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches

I have a product (a 'box') which my customers will add three items to the box product. Is there a way for me to create a multiple choice swatch attribute to allow the users to select the three things they'd like to add to the box?

Put simply, if we were using the color swatch as an example, I'd like to give the user the option of choosing three colors from the swatch attribute. Is that possible?

Comment: As per my knowledge this is not possible..

Comment: Uh oh, that doesn't sound good!

Comment: But you can wait for other community memebers.

Answer (score 0):

Check below repository, It might help you
https://github.com/pmclain/module-multiselect-swatch

Comment: Unfortunately, This solution is not working for me. Is there any other solution?
Thank you.